# How to create a count plot for a nested dataframe in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to use `matplotlib` to visualize the following `pandas` dataframe like shown in the sketch.

The sketch only show what is needed in general terms - there is no need to have the exact layout like it is depicted.

How can I achieve this task using `matplotlib`?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 1, 1,], 'b': [7, 7, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, ], 'c': [102, 102, -50, -50, 30, 10, 10], })
df
   a  b    c
0  0  7  102
1  0  7  102
2  0  3  -50
3  0  3  -50
4  0  1   30
5  1  2   10
6  1  3   10
```

[image: sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting on the visualisation, I would suggest re-shaping your data to make the nesting levels explicit and pre-calculate the frequencies. Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

temp_df = pd.concat([
    df.groupby(["a"])["b"].value_counts().reset_index(name="count").rename(columns={"b":"value"}).assign(level_2="b"),
    df.groupby(["a"])["c"].value_counts().reset_index(name="count").rename(columns={"c":"value"}).assign(level_2="c")
])

final_df = (temp_df
            .rename(columns={"a":"level_1"})
            [["level_1", "level_2", "value", "count"]]
            .sort_values(["level_1", "level_2"]))
```

The resulting dataframe will look like this:

```
   level_1 level_2  value  count
0        0       b      3      2
1        0       b      7      2
2        0       b      1      1
0        0       c    -50      2
1        0       c    102      2
2        0       c     30      1
3        1       b      2      1
4        1       b      3      1
3        1       c     10      2
```

Now to plot values and their counts in this nested way, you can use [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/tutorials/intermediate/gridspec.html) to define the layout based on how many values fall under each nested level. I've hard-coded the values for the purposes of illustrating this toy dataset, but you'd want to handle this programmatically for your real data.

You have 9 values so the `GridSpec` will have 9 columns. You have 2 nested levels, so we reserve 2 bottom rows for nesting labels and add a few more rows to "host" the bar charts.

```
f = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4), dpi=300)

grid = gridspec.GridSpec(10, 9, figure=f)
mpl.rcParams["axes.edgecolor"] = "gainsboro"

# Use context manager to set mpl parameters for nested axs
with mpl.rc_context({"xtick.major.bottom": False, "ytick.major.left": False}):

    # Level 1 axs (label, ax)
    ax_level_1_0 = ("0", f.add_subplot(grid[9, 0:6]))
    ax_level_1_1 = ("1", f.add_subplot(grid[9, 6:]))
    level_1_axs = [ax_level_1_0, ax_level_1_1]

    # Level 2 axs (label, ax)
    ax_level_2_0b = ("B", f.add_subplot(grid[8, 0:3]))
    ax_level_2_0c = ("C", f.add_subplot(grid[8, 3:6]))
    ax_level_2_1b = ("B", f.add_subplot(grid[8, 6:8]))
    ax_level_2_1c = ("C", f.add_subplot(grid[8, 8:]))
    level_2_axs = [ax_level_2_0b, ax_level_2_0c, ax_level_2_1b, ax_level_2_1c]

# Actual count plot axs (level_1, level_2, ax)
ax_0b = (0, "b", f.add_subplot(grid[0:8, 0:3]))
ax_0b[2].set_ylabel("Frequency")

# Hide y-ticks
with mpl.rc_context({"ytick.major.left": False}):
    ax_0c = (0, "c", f.add_subplot(grid[0:8, 3:6]))
    ax_1b = (1, "b", f.add_subplot(grid[0:8, 6:8]))
    ax_1c = (1, "c", f.add_subplot(grid[0:8, 8:]))

count_axs = [ax_0b, ax_0c, ax_1b, ax_1c]

# Remove white space between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

# Add label text to Level 1 and 2 axs
for label, ax in level_1_axs + level_2_axs:
    ax.text(0.5, 0.5, label, horizontalalignment='center',
            verticalalignment='center', transform=ax.transAxes)

    
for l1, l2, ax in count_axs:
    y = final_df.query(f'(level_1 == {l1}) & (level_2 == "{l2}")')["count"]
    labels = final_df.query(f'(level_1 == {l1}) & (level_2 == "{l2}")')["value"]
    x = range(len(y))
    ax.bar(x, y, color="steelblue")
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.tick_params(
        axis="x", direction="in", bottom=False, pad=-20,
        colors="white", labelsize=15)
```

[image]